# Problem with parsing of UTF-8 encoded xml files in Android 3.1 sdk

Tags: android

Xml parsing api is throwing sax parse exception, If i try to parse a xml file which has attributes at root node.

One thing i have noticed is that, this happens if there is a UTF-8 BOM character at the start of the string, if i remove the BOM character things work fine. This code is working fine on 3.0 sdk and below, i saw this problem only in 3.1

am using following parser:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = null;
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
    InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);

    doc = builder.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Document parse(String xml) throws ParsingFailedException {
   try {
      DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

      //encode the xml to UTF -8

      ByteArrayInputStream encXML = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF8"));

      Document doc = builder.parse(encXML);
      log.error("XML parsing OK");

      return doc;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Parser Error:" + e.getMessage());
      throw new ParsingFailedException("Failed to parse XML : Document not well formed", e);
   }
}
```

Comment: sure, thanks this will work I believe because you are passing a input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks evilone,

I have opened a issue with google, and they will be fixing this in their branch.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16892

Comments from google developer:

"I've prepared a fix for the root problem in our internal Honeycomb tree. But you don't need the fix for your code. Your parseXml method should just take an InputStream rather than a String. You can pass that directly to the InputSource constructor."